# Map keywords value to add extra column to long dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df_1_long = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_name': ['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C'],
    'company_country': ['USA', 'Poland', 'Canada'],
    'keyword': ['holding', 'services', 'source'],
    'value': [1,0,1]
    })
```

and the second dataframe:

```
df_training = pd.DataFrame({
     'holding': [1, 0, 0],
     'services': [0, 1, 0],
     'source': [0, 0, 1],
     'sector': ['Retail', 'Finance', 'Energy']
     })
```

The columns in df_training `['holding', 'services', 'source']` are the keywords in column `keyword` in `df_1_long`.

I would like to assign a sector to df_1_long - if 'keyword' in df_1_long value is 1 and in df_training value is 1 for the keyword in a column -> then assign a sector from df_training.

The output should look like that:

```
expected_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_name': ['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C'],
    'company_country': ['USA', 'Poland', 'Canada'],
    'keyword': ['holding', 'services', 'source'],
    'value': [1,0,1],
    'sector': ['Retail', 'no_sector', 'Energy']
    })
```

I tried this piece of code, but I keep getting errors:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_1_long, df_training, left_on='keyword', right_on=df_training.columns[:-1])
df_1_long['sector'] = merged_df['sector'].where(merged_df['value'] == 1, np.nan)
```

Comment: In the merge you are using `df_for_training`, but it should be `df_training` based on the previous code given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape with filter `1` values and get dictionary from `MultiIndex` used for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df_training.set_index('sector').stack().loc[lambda x: x.eq(1)].index.swaplevel()

m = df_1_long['value'].eq(1)
df_1_long['sector'] = np.where(m, df_1_long['keyword'].map(dict(s)), 'no_sector')
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
d = df_training.melt('sector').query('value == 1').set_index('variable')['sector']


m = df_1_long['value'].eq(1)
df_1_long['sector'] = np.where(m, df_1_long['keyword'].map(d), 'no_sector')
print (df_1_long)
  company_name company_country   keyword  value     sector
0    Company A             USA   holding      1     Retail
1    Company B          Poland  services      0  no_sector
2    Company C          Canada    source      1     Energy
```

Comment: Okay, but why it added Finance sector, when the value is 0 ? I would like to assign sectors only when value is 1.

Comment: the problem is - I am trying to assign sectors basing on these keywords occurrences. If the keywords exists in company overview - I assign value 1 to the keyword. then I am using df_training - this is my "model" these specific keywords are telling me what sector I should choose.

Comment: @katarz - Reason was I miss it. Answer was change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html) to reshape and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) those values:

```
mapper = dict(zip(pd.from_dummies(df_training.set_index('sector')).iloc[:, 0],
                  df_training['sector']))

df_1_long['sector'] = (df_1_long['keyword'].map(mapper)
                       .mask(df_1_long['value'].eq(0), 'no_sector')
                       )
```

Output:

```
  company_name company_country   keyword  value     sector
0    Company A             USA   holding      1     Retail
1    Company B          Poland  services      0  no_sector
2    Company C          Canada    source      1     Energy
```

Comment: Had you tested this approach?